# Laravel Relationship in a pivot model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have three tables, one of them is pivot table (and pivot model) and trying to create belongsTo relationship in pivot model (foreign key in pivot table) so that I can get the relevant name from some other table(has primary key). What I want to do is illustrating by images below:
Pivot Table is:
[image]
And other table is:
[image]

It is pivot Model:

```
class MproductIngredient extends Model {

public function qtyType() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\TIngredientType','priQuantityTypeNo');
}
```

}
How to get the relevant name from other table(has primary key).

My code is:

```
@foreach($prd->ingredients a $ingredient)
     "{!! $ingredient->pivot->priQuantityTypeNo !!}"
     @endforeach
```

Comment: does relationship is belongs to one or belongs to many ?

Comment: Basically ,I want to create a belongsTo relationship in pivot model with other table,

Comment: please review answer

Answer (score 0):

Please describe more as far i understand you can make below to relationships

> for belongstoMany

```
    public function qtyTypes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\TIngredientType', 'pivot_table_name', 
          'main_table_id', 'TIngredientType_id');
    }
```

> for hasOne

```
public function qtyType()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\TIngredientType');
    }
```

Comment: No , I don't want to get this, I want to create belongTo relationship from which I want to get the relevant name from other table.Talking about  inverse  relationship.