# name this laravel5.4 eloquent relationship in three tables

Tags: php, database, laravel, relational

I studied eloquent relationships in laravel, i love to use them but today am confuse about relation the following three tables has. 
I have a relation between three tables like:

```
1) companies   {id, company_name}
2) screens     {id, screen_name}
3) company_screen   {id, company_id, screen_id, connected[yes/no] }
```

what type of relation is this in laravel?
how can i fetch screens which are connected(yes), for a company?

Comment: So in other words, a company screen can have many companies and many screens, right?

Comment: Its many to many relationship ..

Comment: Companies and company_screen, screens and company_screen are like manyTomany. You need to use the pivot table here with an extra column `connected`.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many . It is a many to many realtionship and connected is a pivot table column. Inserting and retreiving pivot tables is also explained in the many-to-many docs

Comment: yes you all are correct it's just simple many to many relation with an extra column in pivot table. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after posting my question i read many to many relation in https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships
it's just many to many relation with and extra column in pivot table.

thanks

Comment: Yes all is given in laravel docs so pls before posting such questions pls go to their docs,

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan  yes you are right 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41975152/laravel-relationship-in-a-pivot-model

Comment: @Ahmed ali, it is a different question, relating to pivot table, not relating to relationship, as you see I have not marked any answer on it because the case is different here not as you.